# A Combinatorial Identity Involving Characters of $S_n$ (Reference Request?)

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

It is a well-known exercise that $C_n = \chi_{(n,n)}(1)=\chi_{(n,n)}^{1^n}$ where $C_n$ is the $n$th Catalan number and $\chi_{(n,n)}^{1^n}$ is the character of the irrep $(n,n)$ on conjugacy class $1^n = (1,1,\cdots,1)$.

A related identity that I stumbled across for fixed-point-free involutions is that $\chi_{(n,n)}^{2^n} = \pm \binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$.

I haven't been able to find this stated as an exercise in a textbook or online manuscript, and it seems too obvious to have been overlooked. If you have seen this identity before and recall the reference, I would be happy to know.

Comment: Representing $(n,n)$ on a $2$-runner abacus, this follows very quickly from 2.7.27 in James and Kerber: we have to make $n$ upward bead moves, one bead moving up $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ times, and the other $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ times. (Posted as a comment since I'm sure you know this already, and its only a short proof, not the identity.)

Comment: Feels like it is related to number of SYTs of two-row shape of equal lengths, which are easy to see are in bijection with say Dyck paths... (see Stanleys book on Catalan objects)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a special case of Corollary 2.2 in S. Fomin and N. Lulov, [On the number of rim-hook tableaux](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~fomin/Papers/lulov.ps), taking $r=2$ and $\lambda = (n,n)$. It's probably easier to use the formula in the proof than the corollary itself.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for Mark.  Thanks! I guess the the theory of rim-hook tableaux is a bit too specialized for any of its consequences to appear as exercises.